# using wmic to create a process on localhost as a different user

Tags: windows, cmd, wmi, wmic

Is there a way to create a process with wmic on localhost as a different user.Using something like this:

```
wmic  /node:localhost /user:user  process call create "cmd"
```

I know I can use runas but I'm curious if this is possoble.

May be some of the global switches could help?  (/ROLE,/IMPLEVEL,/AUTHLEVEL,/AGGREGATE,/AUTHORITY ) .Or changing some configuration?
At the moment I get this error:

```
ERROR:
Description = User credentials cannot be used for local connections
```

**EDIT:** this is [the best solution](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1539) that I've found for such cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WMI engine doesn't let you use credentials to connect locally so hence WMIC won't either. RunAs is your best bet.